# How to get unsubscribe URL from Mailchimp list ID API

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm struggling to get the unsubscribe URL from the Mailchimp API. I've managed to find the subscribe URL by accessing `get("lists/{$list_id}/signup-forms");` which returns the following json. However, there's no unsubscribe URL displaying and I can't think of other actions to call apart from signup-forms.

When checking the unsubscribe link in the mailchimp account manually, both the subscribe and unsubscribe links look identical apart from the `/subscribe.` So my next approach would be to get the `subscribe_url_long` and replace the string `subscribe` with `unsubscribe`.

Unless anyone knows a way of accessing the the property from the list ID?

```
    {
   "subscribe_url_long": "https://live.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=XXXXX&id=XXXXX",
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wonders how I fixed this, I managed to grab the following code from the API using the code blow:

```
public
    function get_unsubscribe_url(string $list_id, array $fields = []) {
        $list = $this->get("lists/{$list_id}");
        $subscribe_url = $list['subscribe_url_long'];
        $unsubsribe_link = str_replace('subscribe', 'unsubscribe', $subscribe_url);
        return $unsubsribe_link;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Shaun, do you know how to change the unsubscribe link to a custom link?

Comment: i cannot find a `subscribe_url_long` in the response, should this still work?